# Unable to register kprobe

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'm trying to register a kprobe to retrieve the address of a syscall. But all my attempts seem to return -22 as the error code. The sample code below (incomplete but contains the related functions) tries to register a kernel probe for the `sys_mkdir` call.

It doesn't seem to matter if I specify pre or post handlers, simply registering the probe doesn't work.

Note: I'm trying to use kprobes as a replacement for the unexported `kallsyms_lookup_name` that is no longer exported in kernel 5.7 and above.

```
unsigned long lookup_name(const char *name)  
{
        int ret;
        struct kprobe kp;
        unsigned long retval;
 
        kp.symbol_name = name;
        ret = register_kprobe(&kp);     
        if (ret < 0) {
                printk(KERN_DEBUG "register_kprobe failed for symbol %s, returned %d\n", name,
 ret);
                return 0;
        }
        retval = (unsigned long)kp.addr;
        unregister_kprobe(&kp);
        return retval;
}
                                                                                                  
static int __init mod_init(void)                                                              
{                                                                                                 
        int (*fn)(unsigned long param);

        fn = (void*)lookup_name("__x64_sys_mkdir");   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not initialising the `kprobe` structure in full, so you’re failing the exclusive or requirement between `symbol_name` and `addr` (point 3 in the table in [the `register_kprobe` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/kprobes.html#register-kprobe)): `addr` contains whatever is on the stack on function entry, which is likely to be non-zero, so both `symbol_name` and `addr` are non-zero and `register_kprobe` fails with `EINVAL` (22).

You can fix this as follows:

```c
        int ret;
        struct kprobe kp = {
                .symbol_name = name
        };
        unsigned long retval;
```

which will ensure that the other members of the structure are initialised to their default values.

Comment: That was indeed the issue, thank you for your solution!